# Можно ли сказать: "Возврат долга с юридического лица"?

Tags: грамотная-речь, синтаксис, управление

Встретилось словосочетание "возврат долга с юридического лица". Почему-то напрягает, ощущение, будто фраза корявая. Можно ли говорить: "Возврат долга с юридического лица" или правильнее все-же будет "возврат долга юридического лица" или "возврат долга от юридического лица"? Может быть, есть еще какой-то нормативный вариант?

Answer (score 1):

Возможны два варианта.

Самый лучший, на мой взгляд, вариант: **Возврат долга (кем?) юридическим лицом.**

Но допустимо также: **Возврат долга (чьего?) юридического лица.**

Дополнение.

Оказывается, в Сети несть числа предложениям об оказании помощи кредитору в "возврате долга с физического (юридического) лица". Похоже, это сочетание уже закрепилось в профессиональном сленге юристов и коллекторов. Я думаю, выражение "вернуть долги с" родилось по ассоциации с известным выражением "содрать три шкуры с" :))). И вот доказательство: "*Проще содрать три шкуры с добросовестного, чем вернуть долги с нерадивого владельца квартиры*" (http://bratsk.org/report/show/8341.html). Как сказал классик, всё это было бы смешно, когда бы не было так грустно.

Answer (score 1):

Ответ исправлен.

Правильно: **взыскание  долга с юридического лица.**

Это выражение применяется в юридической практике, а также не противоречит правилам грамматики.

**Взыскание задолженности или возврат долга с юридического лица** – это наиболее востребованная процедура. [Взыскание долга с юридического лица | allvopros.ru](http://www.allvopros.ru/uslugi/vziskanie-zadolzhennosti-dlya-gragdan-i-organizaciy/vziskanie-dolgov-s-yurlic.html)

Из словаря: **ВЗЫСКАТЬ, св. 1. что (с кого).** Юрид. Заставить уплатить (долг, штраф и т.п.).

Comment: "Взыскание долга с юридического лица" не вызывает сомнений в корректности - это и в статьях законов часто встречается. А в юридическом документе (не просто в популярной статье) вам встречалось "возврат...с"?

Comment: Нет, можно сказать "возврат денег с процентами", то есть получение прибыли.

Answer (score 0):

> Встретилось словосочетание "возврат долга с юридического лица"... ощущение, будто фраза корявая.

Она не корявая, она, похоже, из профжаргона всяких там коллекторов и судебных исполнителей. Вот они-то привыкли собирать "долги с кого". Вне этого контекста сочетание действительно может выглядеть косноязычным, лучше поправить, как именно - надо смотреть всю фразу целиком, предложенное М_Г, боюсь, не универсально, если это юридически значимая формулировка.